# Risks of AJAX calls to ASMX

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ajax, web-api

Currently working on an ajax call to an ASP web service (.asmx).

In a situation where I POST to the url/.asmx/WebMethod, am I exposing information of any kind?

In the 'WebMethod' I am running a PostJsonAsync that calls an API and passes along a json string.

As I am still learning, I've been told that calling any public [WebMethod] exposes the code, but I am not sure how that is possible.

Is it possible at all for a user to access the WebMethod server-side code that I have and peek into the API calls that are available?

I've attempted some minor security methods.. We are working with Sitefinity CMS. What I did was call a WebMethod that receives the CurrentUserIdentity and returns a GUID. If the current user is logged in, it returns a valid Guid, if not it returns a Guid full of zeros.

Then, I call the WebMethod containing my API call and post a json object along with the valid or invalid GUID. The server-side WebMethod code will then verify if the GUID is valid and continues based on if a UserProfile can be generated.

To me, this seems to be secure, but I've been told that this still leaves the WebMethod exposed as well as the API. I am however just not understanding what is exposed and what can be used.

If anybody can direct me to any resources that has more information on this, or if anybody can advise me on WebService security, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this classic ASP, not even ASP.NET?

Comment: @RobertHarvey asp.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, there is no difference between calling an ASMX web service vs. any other kind of web service.  The code on the server is not exposed because .cs files are by default not served by Asp.Net, or the code for the ASMX is compiled into an assembly in the bin folder, depending on the type of project (Web Site vs. Web Project) deployed.  It may be possible to discover what other calls are available on your web service depending on how things are configured, but this alone is not a security threat as it would be trivial to discover that anyway (since HTTP traffic can be intercepted).  You should be sure that you're using HTTPS to call the service though to protect the data while its in transit.

Comment: thank you for the great response. i was confused as to what i was exposing.

Comment: @terbubbs No problem; as long as you don't change the defaults to allow .cs files or anything from /bin to be served by Asp.Net, your code should be safe.

Comment: would you say a CodeBehind.cs is more secure after compiling than a ASMX.cs?

Comment: @terbubbs That would just be changing the filename, which wouldn't really have an impact on security (unless you changed the .cs to .htm).  .Net assemblies are easily decompiled if you get one; the thing that is preventing people from getting your code is that Asp.net will not serve files ending in .cs nor will it serve anything in the /bin folder, by default.  It really has nothing to do with your method of deployment, or even technology, as the same would be true for say Java Beans.